# How can I start the GUI for Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu

I just got a 2nd hand pc with ubuntu 16.04.1 I believe, and I am unable to boot into it. It goes straight to a black screen. I've tried the commandline interface and it works, it brings it up just fine, however, when I try the upstart command to start the xfce4, it asks for root, which is something I do not have.

Furthermore, I have tried resetting the root password but, when I try to boot into recovery mode, it again, asks for login and password, and I do not have those either.

I've searched left and right, and all the tutorials show that once you hit the (recovery mode) option from grub, you get straight into the recovery menu, which is not the case for me (asks for login)

I've also tried following a few tutorials that want me to edit the first option from grub, to put it in "rw init=/bin/bash". Once I do this and hit ctrl+x or F10, it tries to boot, but gets stuck at "nonblocking ......"

Is there any way I can bring up the GUI from the commandline without root or, any other method of resettings the root password?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. This helped for me:

```
sudo chown -R currentuser:currentuser /home/currentuser/
```

but I'm thinking this will ask for a sudo password.

Comment: Running `sudo` commands will by definition ask for a `sudo` password.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I didn't get the opportunity to try it tho :/ I guessed the root password and updated the OS, works fine now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a 2nd hand machine I would definitely recommend making a fresh installation of Xubuntu.
If by chance you need the data still in the computer, you can use the "Try Xubuntu" option on the DVD and backup the data before installing.

Comment: I know, my country's mentality is, to format everything and start from 0 when something goes wrong with any OS but, I'm interested in learning on how to deal with different issues, anywho, got it running by guessing the root password and updating the OS, seems like the previous owner didn't let an update finish and it got stuck, all works fine and dandy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to start the display manager. `sudo systemctl start lightdm`